# Parse error on input "=" haskell error

Tags: haskell

When I write only `main = do ...` block, it works perfectly. When I put only `stories = do...` block it also works. Maybe there is an indentation problem.

Here is the code:

```
stories = do
let str0 = "There once was "
str1 <- ["a princess ", "a cat ", "a little boy "]
let str2 = "who lived in "
return (  str0 ++ str1  )

main = do
let len = length stories
putStrLn ("Enter a number from 0 to " ++ show (len - 1))
n <- readLn
putStrLn ""
putStrLn (stories !! n)
```

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

Although this fact is not as advertised as in the case of, say, Python, Haskell does have [syntactically significant indentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation). In your case the code in the bodies of `do`s must be indented:

```
stories = do
    let str0 = "There once was "
    str1 <- ["a princess ", "a cat ", "a little boy "]
    let str2 = "who lived in "
    return (  str0 ++ str1  )

main = do
    let len = length stories
    putStrLn ("Enter a number from 0 to " ++ show (len - 1))
    n <- readLn
    putStrLn ""
    putStrLn (stories !! n)
```

Comment: Just to confirm, the OP's problem is that they're basically trying to define `main` inside the `do` block.